# How do I specify the minimum required .NET framework versions in WiX

Tags: .net, wix

My application is compiled against the .NET 2.0 framework, but I want users to be able to install it on Windows 8 without being prompted to install .NET 3.5. To provide some background info, I have the following app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
    <runtime>
      <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

My question is, in the WiX .wxs file, do I need to specify every version of the framework that my app will run against, such as:

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK20"/>
<Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 2.0. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK20 OR NETFRAMEWORK30 OR NETFRAMEWORK35_CLIENT OR NETFRAMEWORK35 OR NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENT OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL OR NETFRAMEWORK45]]>
</Condition>
```

Or, can I shortcut it and specify something like this:

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK20"/>
<Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 2.0. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK20 OR NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENT]]>
</Condition>
```

Answer (score 1):

when using bootstrapper what you can do is check the windows version and the .net version 
for example here:

```
<ExePackage Id="Netfx45Xxx" Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="no" InstallCommand="/q"
SourceFile="..\SetupProject\dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe"
DetectCondition="(Netfx4FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot;) AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot;))" 
InstallCondition="(VersionNT &gt;= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 &gt;= v6.0) AND (NOT (Netfx4FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot; OR Netfx4x64FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot;))" />
```

So as you can see there is a Detect condition and install condition, which check the windows version and .Net version.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like this statement tries to install .NET 4.5, which isn't my goal.

Comment: well the logic is the same u can install your setup.exe file instead of the .net 4.5 file which is the source file in my case. and instead of checking for .net 4.5 and windows xp you can check for .net 2.0 and u will not be prompted for anything else.